# Complex Drawing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I would like to reproduce this Custom `UIView` which is in `iOS` drawing `Framework`. how i can do this ?

I know that i can use images but is there an other solution ?

[image]

Comment: read the Quartz 2D Programming Guide

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know it's not good what i am doing but it's difficult to me to read all the framework and understand how to do this; i would like if you have any suggestion with some specific Classes, thanks.